# How to fix auto capitalization in ExcelVBA error

Tags: excel, vba

I am still very new at using VBA so many of my code is just pieced together from what I have learned or what I have found while searching how others did things.

The code below keeps giving me

> "Run-time error '13, Type mismatch"

[image]

Basically, its an absence form that prompts the users with a comments box if certain codes are entered.  I added a button to delete all codes and comments but when the button is pushed it gives me the error above and the line in question is: `.Value = UCase(.Value)`.  I have this portion in there because I want all codes entered to be in caps.

The full code is as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Range("C7:AG106").Value = ""

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cmt As Comment
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each cmt In ws.Comments
            cmt.Delete
        Next cmt
    Next ws

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim isect As Range
    With Target
        Set isect = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C7:AG106"))

                If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C7:AG106")) _
      Is Nothing) Then
        With Target
            If Not .HasFormula Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                .Value = UCase(.Value)
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End With
    End If

        If Not isect Is Nothing Then
            If .Text = "U" Then
                On Error GoTo AlreadyHasComment
                .AddComment
                On Error GoTo 0
                .Comment.Visible = True
                .Comment.Text Text:="Explain Unexcused Absense: "
            End If

            If .Text = "E" Then
                On Error GoTo AlreadyHasComment
                .AddComment
                On Error GoTo 0
                .Comment.Visible = True
                .Comment.Text Text:="Explain Excused Absense: "
            End If

            If .Text = "L" Then
                On Error GoTo AlreadyHasComment
                .AddComment
                On Error GoTo 0
                .Comment.Visible = True
                .Comment.Text Text:="Explain Late: "
            End If

            If .Text = "T" Then
                On Error GoTo AlreadyHasComment
                .AddComment
                On Error GoTo 0
                .Comment.Visible = True
                .Comment.Text Text:="Explain Tardy: "
            End If

        End If

    End With

    Exit Sub

AlreadyHasComment:
    ' Do something here, or not.

End Sub
```

Comment: `(ByVal Target As Range)` You are trying to uppercase a range? it does not make sense to me.

Comment: @Daghan no he is not trying to uppercase a range but the `.Value = UCase(.Value)` of a cell. Which indeed does make sense.

Comment: I get the same error when the Debug.Print was added in front of the .Value

Comment: Yes, trying to uppercase a range but also work when I use a delete all button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `Target` can be a range (multiple cells) then `Target.Value` is an array of values and not a single value. That means `.Value = UCase(.Value)` does not work and you must use `UCase` for each cell of `Target` by using a loop.

```
' get all cells that changed and are within C7:AG106
Dim AffectedCells As Range
Set AffectedCells = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C7:AG106"))

If Not AffectedCells Is Nothing Then
    Dim iCell As Range
    For Each iCell In AffectedCells 'loop through that cells and handle each cell on it's own
        With iCell
            If Not .HasFormula Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                .Value = UCase(.Value)
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If

            'you need to include your other If statements here …

        End With
    Next iCell
End If

'and your error handlers go here …
```

---

Finally it should look something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim AffectedCells As Range
    Set AffectedCells = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C7:AG106"))

    If Not AffectedCells Is Nothing Then
        Dim iCell As Range
        For Each iCell In AffectedCells
            With iCell
                If Not .HasFormula Then
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    .Value = UCase(.Value)
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                End If

                If .Text = "U" Then
                    On Error GoTo AlreadyHasComment
                    .AddComment
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    .Comment.Visible = True
                    .Comment.Text Text:="Explain Unexcused Absense: "
                End If

                If .Text = "E" Then
                    On Error GoTo AlreadyHasComment
                    .AddComment
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    .Comment.Visible = True
                    .Comment.Text Text:="Explain Excused Absense: "
                End If

                If .Text = "L" Then
                    On Error GoTo AlreadyHasComment
                    .AddComment
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    .Comment.Visible = True
                    .Comment.Text Text:="Explain Late: "
                End If

                If .Text = "T" Then
                    On Error GoTo AlreadyHasComment
                    .AddComment
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    .Comment.Visible = True
                    .Comment.Text Text:="Explain Tardy: "
                End If
            End With
        Next iCell
    End If

    Exit Sub

AlreadyHasComment:
    ' Do something here, or not.
    Return

End Sub
```

Comment: When I replace what I have with your answers I get an error on the next part regarding the comment box  .Text  = "U"

Comment: @Guaca24 have a look in my edited answer. I put some comments where to put your if statements and your error handler.

Comment: I input that into my file and it def works, the loop takes around 15 seconds to delete all of the cell contents before getting to deleting the comment boxes.  Is there a way to make the process happen faster?

Comment: You might want to ask that at https://codereview.stackexchange.com if there is no error it is off topic here. Also if you original question here is answered please mark it as solved.